# __cxa_finalize and __attribute__

Tags: c++, linux

As far as I know, a program (written with C++ in Linux) calls `__cxa_finalize` when exiting the main function. I create a shared library and use this library in the main function. I want to take some actions when main program loads/unloads this library. I found out that the function `__attribute__` can be used for that purpose when creating the shared library (This function shall be implemented in the shared library code I guess)

I added smth like:

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load(void);

void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_unload(void);
```

and I implemented the functions my_load and my_unload as in the following link:
http://tdistler.com/2007/10/05/implementing-dllmain-in-a-linux-shared-library

The question is exactly in which order these functions are processed when exiting the main function? `my_unload()` function or `__cxa_finalize`?

Answer (score 2):

[gcc documentation for constuctor/destructor attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) says:

> You may provide an optional integer priority to control the order in which constructor and destructor functions are run. A constructor with a smaller priority number runs before a constructor with a larger priority number; the opposite relationship holds for destructors. So, if you have a constructor that allocates a resource and a destructor that deallocates the same resource, both functions typically have the same priority. **The priorities for constructor and destructor functions are the same as those specified for namespace-scope C++ objects.**

In my tests with gcc-4.7.0 however constructor functions run before C++ global object constructors and destructor functions after C++ global object destructors when both are in the same translation unit regardless of the order of declaration/definition.

**Update:** Ian Lance Taylor reported that the order of execution of functions with the constructor attribute and C++ global constructors is not specified. See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-05/msg00118.html

In C++ you can ensure that some object gets initialized before any other global object and gets destroyed after in multiple translation units by using [Schwarz Counter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) idiom.

Comment: To be more explicit, is it possible to ensure that destructor (my_unload) function is executed before __cxa_finalize i.e. destruction of global c++ objects? I want to stop some threads inside my_unload function.

Comment: Try priority argument to destructor attribute.

Comment: How can I set the priorities? What I found out on the Internet is: void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load(void);
void __attribute__ ((destructor (2000))) my_unload(void);

__cxa_finalize() __attribute__ ((init_priority (1999))); The compiler gives an error in such a case: wrong number of arguments specified for destructor attribute. The other point is should I have to set the priority for __cxa_finalize or it has a default priority? My gcc version is 4.1.2

Comment: Not sure if that version of gcc supports priorities.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take some actions when main program loads/unloads this library.

Consider using static class instances for doing that, it's gonna be much more clean and portable.

Basically, you write a class which does initialization work in its constructor (and finalization in destructor), and then declare a static instance of that class. Dynamic linker then does everything for you.

LLVM has nice [class template](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Registry_8h_source.html) which uses this technique for automatically managing a registry of plugins, I'd recommend learning from it.